# Check whether a system of linear equations has a a solution

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

What is the fastest way to check whether a system of linear equations has a solution?

All numbers are rational numbers and the (large) coefficient matrix can be given in the form of SparseArray.

I know that LinearSolve can solve this problem, but if you don't need to know what the solution is, but only need to judge the existence, is there a more efficient method?

The way to calculate rank seems to be slower when there is no solution.

By the way, when I use 'LinearSolve', the form of 'SparseArray' can't help me get faster, even if there are only very limited non-zero elements in each row.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is verifying

```
Det[PseudoInverse[m]] == 0.
```

where `m` is the square matrix of the coefficients.